# IP/name resolve conflict

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a weird problem: IP & name resolve conflicts, here is the code:

```
string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.x.y").HostName; 
                     // output:laptop03

System.Net.IPAddress[] addresslist = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("laptop3");
                    //output:192.168.x.y2
```

You can see, 192.168.x.y was resolved to laptop03, laptop03 was resolved to 192.168.x.y2.

Why are the 2 addresses different?

It is causing my TCP connection failure while using IP address, but TCP connection succeeded by using name

Comment: have you looked up what `System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses` does ..won't this return all IP's found and or connected to the machine or in the DNS..? based on getting the specific one based on namedpipes..? [MSDN Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx) also Charlie, when you debug this how many Ip's are in the addresslist[] array..?

Comment: The correct address is: 192.168.x.y2.

Comment: Assume DNS lies, particularly about reverse lookups.

Comment: Only one address is available and it returns only one.

Comment: [Dns.GetHostEntry Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx) there is a difference please read the 2 so that you will know in the future which functionality to use..

Comment: Thanks. I had another test here:

Comment: IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.x.y2");
hostName = ipEntry.HostName; //output: laptop03

Comment: addresslist = ipEntry.AddressList; //output: Only one address, 192.168.x.y it was not reachable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all DNS records associated with an IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539904/get-all-dns-records-associated-with-an-ip)