# Get all DNS records associated with an IP

Tags: .net, powershell, dns, powershell-4.0

**Background**

The following code returns the IPv4 address of a given alias or host: 
`[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('someDnsName').IPAddressToString`

The below code returns the HostName (CName) and aliases of an IP:
`[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress('172.12.34.56')`

I'd therefore expect anything which returns an IP on `GetHostAddresses` to be listed under the HostName or Aliases of a call to `GetHostByAddress` (or at least for the FQDN of that item to be listed).
i.e. I'd expect the result of the below query to return true

```
cls
$name = 'someName'
$fqdn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($name).HostName 
$ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($fqdn).IPAddressToString
$result = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($ip) 

#this is the result I'd expect to be true
($result.HostName -eq $fqdn) -or ($result.Aliases -contains $fqdn)

#here's additional info to aid in sense checking
"Name: $name"
"FQDN: $fqdn"
"IP: $ip"
"Result: "
(" - HostName: {0}" -f $result.HostName)
" - Aliases: " 
($result | select -ExpandProperty Aliases) | %{("`t{0}" -f $_)}
```

However there are a few A Records which are not behaving in this way.
This may be a misunderstanding of DNS on my part, a misconfiguration of DNS at my company (it's because of DNS anomalies that I'm writing this script; we found 2 servers on the same IP; so I want to check for others), or something else...

**Question**

Is there a way to list all DNS names associated with a given IP address? 
i.e. such that anything which returns an IP from `GetHostAddresses` will be listed in the results of a reverse lookup on the returned IP address?

Comment: I wonder if it'll be enough if you just list all A records on your DNS and search for duplicates in there. You should get all possible IP conflicts from there, if servers are active.

Comment: Thanks Vesper.  That sounds like a suitable solution.  I think `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -RRType 'A'` would do that?  Sadly I can't test as I don't have access / I'm ideally looking for a solution that could be run from my workstation, or any server (I'm part of my company's application services team; not the infrastructure team; just trying to use my scripting abilities to help us monitor for issues in the infrastructure level going forwards).

Comment: ps. this link looks like it provides a number of solutions: http://serverfault.com/questions/550385/export-all-hosts-from-dns-manager-using-powershell (none of these worked on my workstation though, so perhaps this is only possible from the DNS server)

Comment: "a misconfiguration of DNS at my company", yes, it might be that not all records have corresponding reverse dns record

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen; so does that mean there are (at least) two lists in DNS; one `name->IP` and the other `IP->name`, both maintained separately without integrity checks between them?  I guess if that's the case the only solution would be @Vesper's advise of returning all entries, then checking for missing reversing entries.

Comment: Yes, that should do. And yes, there are indeed two lists, one PTR record set, and one A record set.

Comment: Exactly! Assuming that you use Microsoft DNS, if you fire up the DNS Management console and connect to a DNS server, you'll find to groups of DNS zones - Reverse-lookup zones and Forward-lookup zones. CNAME, A, AAAA, SRV etc. are all forward-lookup record types. You can also export a zone or a namespace sub to a textfile and parse it manually

Comment: Strictly speaking zones for forward and reverse lookups are entirely unrelated to each other. Technically it's perfectly fine to have an A record `foo.example.com -> 192.168.23.42` and a PTR record `192.168.13.17 -> foo.example.com`. Or multiple A records and no PTR record (and vice versa). Microsoft's DNS server allows you to define records a little more like what the uninitiated would expect, by associating PTR records with A records, but there's no technical requirement for that.

Comment: For people following this thread, script to check for dns forward/reverse mismatches: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/2c16398b-3348-44c1-a130-e96b8a20c7ae

Comment: Info on forward confirmed dns (i.e. where the ips -> dns name entries are in line with the name -> ip entries): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting a definite list of all names associated with a given IP address is not feasible when you're looking at the global scope, because any DNS admin can define a record for any IP address in their zone. For instance I could easily define an A record `myoverflow.planetcobalt.net.` pointing to the `stackoverflow.com` IP address 198.252.206.16.

It's less impossible if you're reducing the scope to just your organization. However, you still need to enumerate *all* forward lookup zones on your organization's DNS servers and check the address of each A record. The answers to the [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/q/550385/134295) you found do this zone enumeration. You need DNS admin privileges for it, though.

The reason why this gets so complicated is that technically there's no relation between forward and reverse lookup zones. There's no technical requirement for any A record to have any PTR record at all (much less a matching one). You can have two records

```
foo.example.com.             A    192.168.23.42
```

and

```
17.13.113.10.in-addr.arpa.  PTR  foo.example.com.
```

with no problem. Or multiple A records with no PTR record. Or PTR records with no A record.

Microsoft's DNS server allows you to associate a PTR record with an A record, but that's just a convenience feature. Again, there's no technical requirement in the Domain Name System for this association.

Comment: Makes sense; the ability to have a non-symmetrical lookup is surprising to me, but I guess makes sense to those in the know / that there are good reasons for it.  If there are multiple DNS servers within the organisation, should they all be in agreement, or would I also need to run any script on each DNS server as well as for each zone in order to get the full picture of my organisation's IP usage?

Comment: @JohnLBevan That depends on several factors: AD-integration of the zones, domain structure, partitioning, etc. If you have one domain with AD-integrated zones they should normally be synchronized across all DNS servers. I don't know the reason for the disconnect between forward and reverse zones for certain, but I think it's because DNS is a distributed database, and authority over forward and reverse zone(s) isn't necessarily delegated to the same people.